# Editable dropdown in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I am looking to create a dropdown in which user will be presented with a dropdown and when user selects a value from dropdown, s/he can edit the text of the selected value, any ideas how can I achieve it?

Comment: refer the following link

[ click here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249188/implementing-an-editable-dropdownlist-in-asp-net

Comment: [Editable Dropdown list in ASP.NET](http://p2p.wrox.com/book-wroxs-asp-net-2-0-visual-web-developer-2005-express-edition-starter-isbn-978-0-7645-8807-5/53835-editable-dropdown-list-asp-net.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use J Query User interface library for that(http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/):

```
var list = [
        "To Print",
        "Test"
    ];

$("#RefrenceNo").autocomplete({
        source: list 
    });

<div class="field">
    <label id="RefrenceNo-label">Reference No</label>
    <input id="RefrenceNo" name="RefrenceNo"/>
</div>
```